# Problem tikzexternalize with \def

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-external, shell-escape

I am trying to save some plots as individual PDFs, but I want to decide which ones to save with a condition.

`mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}                                                    
\usepackage{tikz}                                                                
\usetikzlibrary{external}                                                        
\usepackage{pgfplots}                                                            
                                                                                 
\tikzexternalize                                                                 
                                                                                                                                    
\begin{document} 
\ifdefined\myRandomVariable                                                                   
\begin{figure}[h]                                                                
    \centering                                                                   
    \begin{tikzpicture}                                                          
        \begin{axis} []                                                          
        \end{axis}                                                               
    \end{tikzpicture}                                                            
\end{figure}                                                                     
\fi                                                                              
\end{document}
```

If I compile it as:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape "\def\myRandomVariable{}\input{mwe}"
```

It fails.

I can `\def\myRandomVariable{}` at the beginning of my file and it works without any problems:

```
\def\myRandomVariable{}                                                          
\documentclass[11pt]{article}                                                    
\usepackage{tikz}                                                                
\usetikzlibrary{external}                                                        
\usepackage{pgfplots}                                                            
                                                                                 
\tikzexternalize                                                                 
                                                                                                                                     
\begin{document} 
\ifdefined\myRandomVariable                                                                  
\begin{figure}[h]                                                                
    \centering                                                                   
    \begin{tikzpicture}                                                          
        \begin{axis} []                                                          
        \end{axis}                                                               
    \end{tikzpicture}                                                            
\end{figure}                                                                     
\fi                                                                              
\end{document}
```

And compiling as:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape mwe
```

How can I achieve what I want? I need to give the condition i.e. `\def` with the compilation command because I need to do this in a bash script with multiple different conditions every time.

Comment: I separate the `\def` and the `input` in my scripts and that seems to work for me, but not sure if that will resolve your issue. So, try `pdflatex -shell-escape "\def\myRandomVariable{}" "\input{mwe}"`

Comment: @PeterGrill It didn't work for me. Does it work for you with my MWE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following log lines indicate the problem is, when `external` calls extra latex commands, `\myRandomVariable` is always undefined.

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "pgfplots-external-sx625091-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{pgfplots-external-sx625091}\input{pgfplots-external-sx625091}"' ========
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
system returned with code 256
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
```

Configuring the key `external/system call` seems to work:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzexternalize

\makeatletter
\ifdefined\myRandomVariable
  \tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
    -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\string\def\string\myRandomVariable{}\texsource"}}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ifdefined\myRandomVariable
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} []
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: This completely solves the MWE above. I have a follow-up question, but I think it is more appropriate to have it separate. Could you please have a look? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625155/externalize-different-tikz-pictures-depending-on-combination-of-conditions